# Ubuntu 13.10 freezing on splash screen (boot screen) after upgrade from 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, upgrade, freeze, 13.10

I just updated my ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 using the built in update software. After the restart it asked me to do, the system is stuck, frozen on the splash screen (ubuntu logo with all circles orange,  the boot screen ).

I'm running on a Lenovo IdeaPad y510p duel booting with windows 8.

I would like all my files and programs to be kept as they are so please don't suggest formatting.

Comment: Use the "nomodeset" (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) to boot and then configure the graphics drivers.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on one of my upgrades today.

It's because the login manager isn't starting.

I'm using xubuntu with lightdm.

I couldn't figure out how to fix it so I ended up SSH into the box from another, but you could probably press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get into **tty1** CLI Mode.

Then I ran this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
```

I'm guessing you could replace "xubuntu-desktop" with "ubuntu-desktop" or "kubuntu-desktop" depending on your flavor.

After a reboot, I was new and improved!

Comment: Oh nice, how did you know the ssh login information?

Comment: It was an "upgrade" so all of the user/login/pass information stayed the same.

Comment: this did not work for me, same problem .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but reinstalling `xubuntu-desktop` did not solve it. On the other hand it was perfectly possible to login from virtual console 2 and `startx` from here.

I finally stumbled upon this answer: [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/141607#141607). It turned out that after the upgrade to 13.10, `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` insisted on using `unity-greeter` instead of `lightdm-gtk-greeter` which is the only one that was installed. After editing the configuration file, everything is fine.

Comment: I can't get to the virtual console, when I click Cntrl Alt F1-F6 it does nothing. I basically can't do anything because the system haven't really booted up (I guess)

Comment: I am in the same situation as Dan Barzilay.  It boots to the ubuntu logo screen and that's it.  No text. No information. None of the CTRL+ALT+Fx options work.